# Keydown Simulator

Tags: python, simulator, keydown, ime

I made a IME simulator like under the link.

http://colspan.net/hangulime/ <- this is really important link to understand my question.

This simulator express when you type english. it convert korean one by one. (w converts ㄱ, when k after w, it converts 가 by real time simulating.)

I have already made converter from english to hangul by using raw_input() method.

I want to make converter from english to korean not using raw_input method(by real time like upper link), because it is take a string and convert to new string by mealy machine.

Can I use sys library and Tkinter library to use express like upper link?

Comment: What exactly is your question? From what I can derive, you are asking us to do the program for you.

Comment: Sorry. I think you have typed some string on that link that you could have understood what magic is.